# Azure App Service Switch Database from Primary to Secondary and Vice Versa

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

We have Azure App Service and Azure Sql Database, this database is updated on from on premise and we are thinking to have two databases to have transactional integrity and switch App Service to primary to secondary and vice versa whenever load is complete. How can we do it smoothly while using Azure App Service with minimal or no downtime?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

Comment: Thanks , it looks like it will work , is there way to automate it using ADF pipeline once data load is complete ?  When I say automate it means swapping of the slot using ADF pipelines assuming once data load is complete using ADF pipeline and we want to swap the space .

Comment: @xslguy no, there isn't a way can automate it.

Comment: Hi Leon , if I understand correctly we can not swap in automatic fashion and it has be done by someone manually once you get notification once your data load is complete .

Comment: @xslguy yes, you're right~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure document [Set up staging environments in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) provided by @CSharpRocks should solve your problem. For you another question, your understand is correct.

Just for now, we can't a way can automate these settings.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation , another question how do I configure my pipeline with two different sink , do you think having two pipeline will be better approach or store flag in the database and check , any idea about best practices in such scenario where ADF is moving data to two different sink alternatively . e.g first pipeline run goes in db1 and second pipeline goes in db2 if first pipeline run is successful , any thoughts ?

Comment: Hi @xslguy,  I see the new question. I will check it. By the way, If my answer is helpful for you, hope can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.